# How to hide virtual keyboard without losing focus on input field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I'm running chromium in kiosk mode. When user clicks on Login button, he is taken to the page where hidden input field is present (the focus is set programatically and the keyboard is obviuosly brought up). User then uses his RFID card and the code is scanned into the hidden field. The keyboard is a bad thing, because the user can type something before scanning his card - obviously the scanned code is wrong and the login is rejected.

I tried many things, like simulating the clicks to hide the keyboard, but I lose focus of the input field and the RFID code isn't read at all.

Few other options I considered were: RFID code is read pretty much instantly, but if the user decides to write something, it will take some more time. I could detect the times between those clicks, and if the time > 0.1s (or something like that) - set the value of input field to "". I also considered using regex, to determine if the inserted string looks as it should.

Those 2 options might work, but would be horrible to implement and the keyboard is still shown.